# How to prevent Ubuntu booting into X

Tags: boot, xorg, ubuntu-14.04, runlevel

I am actually wondering how to prevent services (in this case the X server) in Ubuntu (14.04) from startup automatically at boot time. I tried:

```
sudo update-rc.d lightdm remove
```

and

```
sudo update-rc.d lightdm stop 2 3 4 5
```

but the session managager starts up nevertheless. What piece of Ubuntus startup system I have to work with in order to do the job?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is configured within a parameter in the GRUB default file.

Edit your `/etc/default/grub` file and there should be a parameter called `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`. Change its value to `text`.

After that, don't forget to update your `GRUB` config:

`sudo update-grub2`

Comment: Ugh - That worked out for me. Thanks! I now could start X manually by issuing "sudo service lightdm start". But I really think the Ubuntus startup/service system is quite a bit too decentralized... I would never have come to the idea that this could be configured within the GRUB configurations :(